# ROR passing array as parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, parameter-passing

I am trying pass array as parameter to my controller method but it's not working for me. I tried it in following ways:

```
http://localhost:3000/med?med_ids=[2,1]
```

I tried in following way as well and its working for me. I just want to know any good solution

```
http://localhost:3000/manufacturer/1/medicines?medicine_id[]=2&medicine_id[]=1
```

inside controller:

```
@val = params[:medicine_id]
```

values are coming but I want to make it as array.

Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: What are you getting in `params[:medicine_id]`

Comment: You could JSON encode your array and then parse it from your controller

Comment: I am getting as string

Comment: Try: `?medicine_id%5B%5D=2&medicine_id%5B%5D=1`

Comment: If I am reading question correctly, `?medicine_id[]=2&medicine_id[]=1` is working for you. And this is the correct way to pass array in query string

Comment: @JosephLeBrech Thank you for quick replay. I tried your solution and its working fine for me. Only thing I am worried about if I pass simple value instead of array then how to handle exception. By Begin and rescue or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to send parameter like [1,2], then in your controller you will get like "[1,2]",

and you need to parse for get in original array like:
JSON.parse "[1,2]"

ans: [1,2] and class Array

Answer (score 6):

You cannot get array from query string like this:

```
?med_ids=[2,1]
```

If you want to pass an array in query string, you need to pass it as follow (as you have mentioned in question):

```
?medicine_id[]=2&medicine_id[]=1
```

As an answer to your question: 2nd way is absolutely good way and correct way. Go with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can optionally build your controllers to parse a delimited array:

```
?medicine_ids=1,2
```

controller:

```
medicine_ids = params[:medicine_ids].split(',')
```